# CSS background attachment fixed + fixed background size width

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position

I am trying to add a "strip" of an image to the left top of the div as a background with a fixed attachment property. Here it is:
https://jsfiddle.net/mvfariajr/recLr6yf/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(http://ariseartgroup.com/interiors/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/metal-texture-trim.jpg);
}
```

The issue is that the background isn't always to the left of the div.

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to just run the image left top to bottom with no repeat

Comment: Yes, but with fixed property.

Comment: @MichaelCoker There is no difference between your result than mine. I am trying to have a fixed attachment property + a 70px fixed width with top left positioning.

Comment: @Marcio sorry, I made the changes in dev tools and didn't update the fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/recLr6yf/3/

Comment: It's not quite working in my site still. Check this out: http://ariseartgroup.com/interiors/about/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  background:white url("http://ariseartgroup.com/interiors/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/metal-texture-trim.jpg") 10% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 70px 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to have background-attachment: fixed

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed it. In that case you need to have the `background-position` set with respect to the `width`. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Marcio is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/tpb1v3nt/) what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you! But it still not working properly in my site for some reason.  http://ariseartgroup.com/interiors/about/ Which is inside div.metal-left

Comment: `fixed` means ***relative to viewport***. You probably want to try  `background-position: calc((100vw - 1097px) / 2) 50%` - the `1097px` comes from `1080px` container width and `17px` scroll-bar in Chrome and Firefox. But you don't really want to go that path. Because device with slim scrollbar will look bad. You're much safer using a `pseudo-element` on your container div, with `position:absolute;` and `width: 70px`. You can than repeat your background and it will always show correctly, as long as you set it to repeat.

Comment: I tried using :before prior but it didn't really make any difference because I dont want the image to repeat since its not a pattern. Foes that make send? Are you saying to set the width to 70px and set to repeat but it actually not going to repeat?

Comment: What you say does make sense, but I think it would be the best solution cross-browser. It's an image that can easily be made to repeat itself on `x` direction without being noticeable, especially since you only use it in a stripe of `70px`.

Comment: The image its not really a pattern. But I will give it a shot to see how it looks VS "calc" at background-position. Thank you a bunch!